# Intermittent MySql errors in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I intermittently get the following error on different tables.

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql::Error: : INSERT INTO `sessions`
>   (`created_at`, `data`, `session_id`, `updated_at`) VALUES (?, ?, ?,
>   ?)):

This is with activerecord 3.1.4.

Please let me know if any other information would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because I was using

```
reconnect: true
```

in my database config.

After I removed this, I am not seeing this error any more.